# How to position an added widget to a layout based on another widget in the same layout?

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

In my GUI, I would like to add a `QComboBox` to a `verticalLayout` programmatically based on a a signal triggered by specific action. The following code works fine and the widget is added:

```
QComboBox* userOptions = new QComboBox();
ui->verticalLayout_13->addWidget(userOptions);
```

However, this way the widget is always added to the end of the layout.

My question is: how to position the added `QComboBox` to the `verticalLayout` in alignment to another widget in the same layout ? (i.e.: above the "Go" push button for example)

Comment: Do you really need to create a new QComboBox ? Because you could let it in the layout and set it visible or not whether you need it or not.

Comment: @YMoreau: I just used the visibility property as you suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to explicitly insert an item in a layout where you want it to be.

You have a few choices to achieve that the "hard" way:

- use `QLayout::takeAt(int index)` to take all items after the index you want to insert at, insert your item, then insert back the taken items.
- create a placeholder widget which you can use to reserve an index in the layout, then you don't insert the item in the layout, but in a layout nested inside the placeholder widget. Without an item, the placeholder widget takes no space, and expands to accommodate whatever is put into it.
- implement your own `QLayout` subclass which supports inserting at a specific index. There are several functions you will have to implement.

EDIT: An omission on my end, as Kuba Ober noted, most of the concrete layout implementations support inserting at a specific index, for example `QBoxLayout` derived have insert methods which pass an index as a parameter.

Comment: It looks like a lot of unnecessary "hard" work for what I thought it will be a nice and easy skill to learn. As far as my application is concern, I will stick to the first line in your answer (for now at least), and use visibility property as "Y Moreau" suggested. Thanks

Comment: You might want to look at the documentation of concrete layouts again. Yes, there's no way of doing it using only the `QLayout` interface, but all concrete layouts definitely support it. `QGridLayout` doesn't let you insert directly, but you can easily enough shuffle existing items to make room for the new one.

Comment: @KubaOber - yes, it is true, I haven't noticed before, mainly because I haven't used layouts all that much, and most of the time - in a static scenario. I am mostly using QML, and QML layouts don't have that at all.

Comment: In QML if you don't use layouts it's IIRC possible to rebind the positions to change the visual layout on the fly, too.

Answer (score 1):

First, iterate a layout to find the index of the reference item you're inserting relative to. Then use the concrete layout's specific widget insertion/addition functionality.

Since you presumably use a `QBoxLayout`, you'd use its `insertWidget` method to insert a widget.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/insert-widget-36746949
#include <QtWidgets>

namespace SO { enum InsertPosition { InsertBefore, InsertAfter }; }

bool insertWidget(QBoxLayout * layout, QWidget * reference, QWidget * widget,
                  SO::InsertPosition pos = SO::InsertBefore, int stretch = 0,
                  Qt::Alignment alignment = 0) {
   int index = -1;
   for (int i = 0; i < layout->count(); ++i)
      if (layout->itemAt(i)->widget() == reference) {
         index = i;
         break;
      }
   if (index < 0) return false;
   if (pos == SO::InsertAfter) index++;
   layout->insertWidget(index, widget, stretch, alignment);
   return true;
}
```

Similar functions can be easily devised for `QFormLayout`, `QGridLayout` and `QStackedLayout`.

And a test harness:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QWidget w;
   QVBoxLayout l{&w};
   QLabel first{"First"};
   QLabel second{"Second"};
   l.addWidget(&first);
   l.addWidget(&second);
   insertWidget(&l, &first, new QLabel{"Before First"}, SO::InsertBefore);
   insertWidget(&l, &second, new QLabel{"After Second"}, SO::InsertAfter);
   w.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```